# Validation query

Tags: oracle, jdbc

By default for Oracle Databases validation query is "select 1 from [dual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm)".
[Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) says:

> ValidationQuery - If specified, this query MUST be an SQL SELECT
>   statement that returns at least one row.

Based on sentences above, can I modify a validation query that will be:

1. nested or conditioned query
2. from another table I specify
3. this table has one row and multiple columns

I've read a lot of documentation, but didn't find any information to say that's impossible or at least incorrect.

Comment: you can, but why would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be any valid query - from the [Tomcat JDBC documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html):

> (String) The SQL query that will be used to validate connections from this pool before returning them to the caller. If specified, this query does not have to return any data, it just can't throw a SQLException. The default value is null. If not specified, connections will be validation by the isValid() method. Example values are SELECT 1(mysql), select 1 from dual(oracle), SELECT 1(MS Sql Server)

You asked about using nested queries, different tables and multiple columns and so I give you something to think about:

The `validationQuery` is executed ***every time*** an application requests a connection from the pool. This is *before* the application issues it's own query - so at a minimum you issue two queries against the database. With that in mind, why would you want to make the query more complex? All you would do is add unnecessary load on the database server for no reason at all - AFAIK you cannot see the output of the `validationQuery` within a Java application because it happens at the container level *before* the connection is passed to the client.

Keep it simple and use one of the recommended queries.

Comment: Nah... `SELECT * FROM absolutely_huge_table;` would be much better to check if the server's running! :-)

Comment: Also to [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name): because I want to solve the problem of application jdbc pool that can't be reset and gives me ORA exception when trying to get DB's packages that's being recompiling at the moment. Standard resource attributes like testOnBorrow="true" and validationQuery="select 1 from dual" didn't help.

Comment: I want to create something like a simple one-row table with packages' states (determined as 0 or 1) get SELECT result by subqery (e.g. SUM) returned value with condition statements help. Do I understand correctly validationQuery returned value is table row content or null?

Comment: You can could do something like:  select my_validation_function from dual, where within "my_validation_function" you could conduct whatever probes, tests, etc you like

Comment: @Dmitresso I think it would make sense that you post your real problem in a new question.

Comment: @miracle173 It was ehough to understand a mechanism to solve my problem. The problem itself too big not so interesting and I can't see whole picture to desribe it.

Comment: @Dmitresso ok, it is fine that your question could be answered